# JQuery validate ignore localization files (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

In my ASP.NET MVC application I added validation attributes to my model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I also added localization files to my HTML:

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/localization/messages_de.js"></script>
```

However, validation messages are still not translated and I only see english messages. The generated HTML looks like this:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="">
```

How can I make localization works with ASP.NET MVC without creating my own translations on the server side? I would like to use the existing javascript localizations.

Answer (score 0):

The script you have included in your HTML contains error messages for the jQuery validation plugin. The Required data annotation attribute that you have decorated your model property with is an ASP.NET validation system.

Although the data annotation system does provide client-side validation, the error messages that it uses are attached to attributes in the markup on the server, using ASP.NET's localization system.

Assuming you can find error messages that would serve your purpose in the jquery message file, one way of utilising them would be to use the ErrorMessage attribute of the DataAnnotation attributes inject a message key for the property rather than the error message itself. You can then add a jQuery function to your view that would pick up the key from the relevant attribute of the invalid element (eg data-val-required) to look up and replace the attribute's content with a string retrieved from the message file.

So (in outline):

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="messageKey")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var elem = $("input[data-val-required]");
    elem.val(function lookupMessage() {
        var key = elem.val();
        var message = dosomethingWith(key); // lookup value
        return message;
    });
});
```